# ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer bidirectional_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Tags: python, lstm, bidirectional

it's the error on this codes,and it happens when i tried to add biLSTM after CNN, I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Plz help or try to give some ideas how to make these right thx~

it seems to be the error of input, lstm needs 3 dimensions but i only have 2,but i try to raise dimension by
x = lambda x: K.expand_dims(x, axis=-1)

but it shows another error that "All inputs to the layer should be tensors"
so i'm running out of ideas, plz help~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
inputs1 = Input(shape=(200, 1))
x1 = inputs1

x1 = Conv1D(64, kernel_size=3, kernel_initializer="he_normal", kernel_regularizer=l2(l),bias_regularizer=l2(l))(x1) 
x1 = BatchNormalization()(x1) 
x1 = Activation("relu")(x1) 
x1 = MaxPooling1D(3, strides=2)(x1) 

x1 = Flatten()(x1) 
inputs2 = Input(shape=(9,)) 
x2 = inputs2 

x = Concatenate()([x1, x2]) 

x = BatchNormalization()(x) 
x = ReLU()(x) 
x = lambda x :K.expand_dims(x , axis=-1) 
x = Bidirectional(CuDNNLSTM(64, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None, 1)))(x)
x = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x)
```

and the error are as follows:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 310, in assert_input_compatibility
K.is_keras_tensor(x)
File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 697, in is_keras_tensor
str(type(x)) + '`. ' ValueError: Unexpectedly found an instance of type` <class 'function'>`. Expected a symbolic tensor instance.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/paper with codes/latest/Deep-Neural-Network-For-Heartbeat-Classification-master/main.py", line 202, in 
main()
File "C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/paper with codes/latest/Deep-Neural-Network-For-Heartbeat-Classification-master/main.py", line 173, in main
model = create_model(l=1e-3)
File "C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/paper with codes/latest/Deep-Neural-Network-For-Heartbeat-Classification-master/main.py", line 105, in create_model
x = Bidirectional(CuDNNLSTM(64, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None, 1)))(x)
File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\wrappers.py", line 437, in **call**
return super(Bidirectional, self).**call**(inputs, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 446, in **call**
self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 316, in assert_input_compatibility
str(inputs) + '. All inputs to the layer '
ValueError: Layer bidirectional_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'function'>. Full input: [<function create_model.. at 0x000001AF1D00BE18>]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.

Comment: Can you post the complete code so that we can replicate the issue? Refer to this link [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: like this ,i try to add the bilstm after the cnn

Comment: Hey @YvonneCollins please edit your post with code and full error traceback so better to understand and don't put this in comment!

Comment: OK, i'll try,i'm new to this site,sorry~